# Как посчитать сумму элементов в чётных и нечетных строках и столбцах?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дана матрица размера N*M. Нужно посчитать сумму элементов в чётных и нечетных строках и столбцах.

Первую часть программы я составил, а вот вторую, убей бог, не получается.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int N, M, i, j;
    int result4etn;
    int resultne4etn;
    cout << "Введите колл строк матрицы:";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Введите колл стоб матрицы: ";
    cin >> M;
    int** mass = new int* [N]; //создаем массив указателей на элементы
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Заполните матрицу " << N << 'х' << M << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        mass[i] = new int[M]; //создаем массив элементов
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout << "Введите число: ";
            cin >> mass[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "Полученная матрица: " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout << mass[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код

Comment: Ну так просто поменяйте местами индексы :) Словом, приведите код...

Comment: И где же у вас первая часть программы? сумма элементов в каждой четной, нечетной строке?... Кстати, приведенная программа у вас тоже не рабочая...

Comment: @Harry, я так понимаю, первая часть - это "Дана матрица размера N*M." ;-)

Comment: @PavelParshin Так у него и матрицы этой нет!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Замените свой вывод матрицы на

```
int
    sum_even_rows = 0,
    sum_odd_rows  = 0,
    sum_even_cols = 0,
    sum_odd_cols  = 0;

cout << "Полученная матрица: " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0) // четные строки
            sum_even_rows += mass[i][j];
        else
            sum_odd_rows += mass[i][j];

        if (j%2 == 0) // четные столбцы
            sum_even_cols += mass[i][j];
        else
            sum_odd_cols += mass[i][j];

        cout << setw(6) << mass[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "Сумма элементов в четных строках   :  " << sum_even_rows << endl;
cout << "Сумма элементов в нечетных строках :  " << sum_odd_rows  << endl;
cout << "Сумма элементов в четных столбцах  :  " << sum_even_cols << endl;
cout << "Сумма элементов в нечетных столбцах:  " << sum_odd_cols  << endl;
```

Здесь считаем столбцы/строки с нулевого (т.е. самый первый - четный).

Answer (score 1):

Решение короче и без `if`

```
int T[2][2] = {};
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<M;j++)
        T[i&1][j&1]+=E[i][j];
cout << "Сумма элементов в четных строках   :  " <<T[0][0] + T[0][1]<<endl;
cout << "Сумма элементов в нечетных строках :  " <<T[1][0] + T[1][1]<<endl;
cout << "Сумма элементов в четных столбцах  :  " <<T[0][0] + T[1][0]<<endl;
cout << "Сумма элементов в нечетных столбцах:  " <<T[0][1] + T[1][1]<<endl;
```